# Statistics from the Bayesian point of view

Tags: reference-request

I am looking for text book that develops the theory of statistics from assuming nothing more than Bayes Theorem. Could you please refer me to material? I would prefer text books and papers, however lecture notes / video lectures are also fine.

Thanks!

p.s.: I am not sure if the question is right for the website. I have seen others ask similar questions. Please notify me, if the question needs to be removed / edited.